# Does the radius of the atom change when an electron is excited?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

> The radius of the atom increases when the electron in a hydrogen atom undergoes a transition from the 1s-orbital to a 2p-orbital.

How is this possible? Why does exciting an electron to a higher energy state increase the radius of the atom?

Comment: Related: [Angular and radial nodes](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/8655/4945) [Why is the 2s orbital lower in energy than the 2p orbital when the electrons in 2s are usually farther from the nucleus?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/152/4945) [Atomic radius definition disproved - Bohr's model to Schroedinger's wave equation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/59096/4945) [What is the difference between the mean radial distance and the most probable radial distance of an orbital?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/95045/4945)

Comment: This can be anything from a very short to a very long story, depending on how much you already know. What is a hydrogen atom, to begin with? What is it made of?

Comment: Atomic radii are not very well defined. tl;dr: the *'average radius'* / most probable distance is larger for a 2p orbital than for the 1s.

Comment: If an atom is excited by a large amount of energy to close to its ionisation energy, its size becomes vast compared to that at its lowest energy. In the Bohr model the radius increases as $n^2$ when $n$ is the principle quantum number.  Search for Rydberg atoms.

Comment: See also Rydberg atoms. E.g for an atom of potassium, and an electron excited to n=600, the electron occurs up to 0.1 mm far from the kernel.

Comment: As for the just above, you can get a sense of it already with rudimentary models.